# Rails: How to get existing working page/url to stop working and go to 404?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an existing page that works. But I want to remove it now so that when people go to the URL, it renders a 404. I deleted the view and commented out the action in the controller, which sent me to a 404 in development, but when I deployed it to production and went to the URL it gave me a 501 Not Implemented instead. Is there a formula to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you remove the route from routes.rb?

Comment: it's currently using one of the wildcard routes, so it's hard to remove. it's using `map.connect ':action/:id', :controller => "site"`. is there an `except`?

Comment: i eventually fixed it by adding this to my action `raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')`